# How to consume servlet ClientResource with URL parameters?

Tags: java, rest, restlet, clientresource

I have a restlet resource mapped as follows:

```
router.attach("/activities/{userid}/{criteria}/{value}", ActivitiesResource.class);
```

I am testing the resource from cmd line with curl and it works OK. Now I want to consume it from another resource. [Looking at the documentation](http://wiki.restlet.org/docs_2.1/13-restlet/27-restlet/328-restlet/285-restlet.html), I understand I should be able to do something like this:

```
// create client resource for the activities
ClientResource clientResource = new ClientResource("http://localhost:8888/myApp/activities/");

// wrap 
IActivitiesResource activitiesResource = clientResource.wrap(IActivitiesResource.class);

// invoke a given method
JsonRepresentation result = activitiesResource.getActivites();
```

My question (assuming the above looks OK): **how do I pass the parameters mapped in the url (userid, criteria, value) to the client resource**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can add the parameters to the uri that you are passing to the ClientResource.
for example:

```
 ClientResource clientResource = new ClientResource("http://localhost:8888/myApp/activities/123/weight/70");
```

Hope that helps.